# Hide / Remove "Create" button on DetailView of sugarcrm

Tags: php, sugarcrm

In one of my sugar custom module, I don't need "Edit" and "Create" buttons on the DetailView. I have successfully removed "Edit" button, using following code in view.detail.php file.

```
unset($this->dv->defs['templateMeta']['form']['buttons'][0]);
unset($this->dv->defs['templateMeta']['form']['buttons'][1]);
unset($this->dv->defs['templateMeta']['form']['buttons'][2]);
unset($this->dv->defs['templateMeta']['form']['buttons'][3]);
```

now I want to get rid of the "Create" button from the DetailView. I have search for it but didn't get anything useful. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

Just find the detailviewdefs.php of your module and copy them to custom/modules/{yourmodulenamehere}/matadata/
and remove the button you dont want to have from the buttons array:
(Here are the detailviewdefs of the module Meetings for example)

```
$viewdefs ['yourmodulenamehere'] = 
array (
  'DetailView' => 
  array (
    'templateMeta' => 
    array (
      'form' => 
      array (
        'buttons' => 
        array (
          0 => 'EDIT',
          1 => 'DUPLICATE',
          2 => 'DELETE',
          3 => 
          array (
            'customCode' => '{if $fields.status.value != "Held"} <input type="hidden" name="isSaveAndNew" value="false">  <input type="hidden" name="status" value="">  <input type="hidden" name="isSaveFromDetailView" value="true">  <input title="{$APP.LBL_CLOSE_AND_CREATE_BUTTON_TITLE}"  accesskey="{$APP.LBL_CLOSE_AND_CREATE_BUTTON_KEY}"  class="button"  onclick="this.form.status.value=\'Held\'; this.form.action.value=\'Save\';this.form.return_module.value=\'Meetings\';this.form.isDuplicate.value=true;this.form.isSaveAndNew.value=true;this.form.return_action.value=\'EditView\'; this.form.isDuplicate.value=true;this.form.return_id.value=\'{$fields.id.value}\';"  name="button"  value="{$APP.LBL_CLOSE_AND_CREATE_BUTTON_TITLE}"  type="submit">{/if}',
          ),
          4 => 
          array (
            'customCode' => '{if $fields.status.value != "Held"} <input type="hidden" name="isSave" value="false">  <input title="{$APP.LBL_CLOSE_BUTTON_TITLE}"  accesskey="{$APP.LBL_CLOSE_BUTTON_KEY}"  class="button"  onclick="this.form.status.value=\'Held\'; this.form.action.value=\'Save\';this.form.return_module.value=\'Meetings\';this.form.isSave.value=true;this.form.return_action.value=\'DetailView\'; this.form.return_id.value=\'{$fields.id.value}\'"  name="button1"  value="{$APP.LBL_CLOSE_BUTTON_TITLE}"  type="submit">{/if}',
          ),
        ),
      ),
      'maxColumns' => '2',
      'widths' => 
file goes on........
```